# Ajax select2 example

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm needing to download names of cities in a comboBox Select2 via ajax, but so far it has not worked. many examples in internet search, but not understand them too.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/city?";
    $("#city").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            delay: 500,
            data: function (term) {
            return {
                city: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.text,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
});
```

y este es el código json que devuelve mi servidor con la consulta realizada:

```
[{ "id": 1, "text": "Capital, Córdoba, Argentina" }]
```

Dice "Searching...." y luego "No results found"

Really, Thanks!

Comment: I miss SO in my native language :-(

Comment: cud someone translate to english.

Comment: "and this is the json that my server returns with the finished query (not sure about the last part)" ... "it says Searching... and then No results found"

Comment: Are you sure url = "http://localhost:8000/api/city?";  is working ?

Comment: which version of `select2` are you using? also, post the html for `#city` element.

Answer (score -1):

First of all if you are using Select2 version 4+, make sure you initialize select2() on a `<select>` element or many of his feature like AJAX will be turned off.

Select2 will need a formated answer from your server at : `http://localhost:8000/api/city?`

Response returned by your server should look like this:

```js
[
    {id:1,text:'city1'},
    {id:2,text:'city2'},
]
```

The options:
`minimumInputLength = 0`, will make it load the whole list on click
`minimumResultsForSearch` , control how many results you need to display the search box into select2 list.

`ajax{data: function(param)}` is the function called to format the user data into something your server will understand, what you return here is send to your `{ajax:url}`

`ajax{processResults: function (data, status)}` , this is called when you ajax got a successful response from your server , `data` will be the response from your server this is the last chance you have to make sure that `data` is formated like select2 need , see top of this post. What you return here is send to select2.

Hope it help!